# Output Name same as Input with "_EDC" appended

Tags: append

I am new to coding.

I am Trying to write a script where the output name, after projecting the data is the same as the input name, but with "_EDC" appended.  I would like SGE_Centerline_2017_0201 to carry over with "_EDC" appended after it is projected.

Comment: Linux, Windows, MacOSX, VAX VMS, PDP/11, ... ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.